# Why is my app trying to use drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png?

Tags: android, android-layout

The app works fine on HPDI and MDPI, but when run in an LDPI (v2.0) emulator, I get the exception and stack trace below.

Why is it looking for this image? (it's not referenced in my application, I've checked). The starter activity has disabled the title bar in any case.

If the OS expects this image, why is it not present?

Why is the exception relating to an MPDI image, when the emulator is LDPI?

```
04-20 11:35:19.432: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(236): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-20 11:35:19.502: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spondle/com.spondle.EventsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
        at com.spondle.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
        ... 23 more
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1710)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:115)
        ... 27 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:391)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1702)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: Try to put the same image (with the same name and content) into ldpi folder.

Comment: The image is nothing to do with my project, it doesn't exist in any of the folders.

Comment: I don't see how the code is relevant here, as I'm not using that image. As you can see in the stack trace, my activity calls setContentView() and it blows up as the framework is attempting to use this image - I want to understand why.

Comment: Try clean project... so what u have in code and layout?

Comment: The resource does not exist in my project. A clean build makes no difference. Happy to post code where it's relevant, but no idea what is relevant, hence the question.

Comment: in you project no but in android platform yes, and your aps is using it ;P check there ANDROID_SDK_PATH/platforms\android-7\data\res\drawable-mdpi that you have there that file, even you'll disable it

Comment: The exception is being thrown on a brand new phone, purchased for testing, which is v2.1 and LDPI. Clearly the image is not present, but as I said in my question, why is the app looking for it?

Answer (score 3):

**If the OS expects this image, why is it not present?**

**Why is the exception relating to an MPDI image, when the emulator is LDPI?**

If the requested resource (title_bar_shadow.9.png) is not present in drawable-ldpi (and it wasn't until Android 2.3), Android will try to find the best match (drawable-mdpi will be the next folder to search in). Anyway, the file will not be found there either (again, it was not there until Android 2.3). So the next step would be to search for it in drawable-hdpi (where it can be found). But apparently the search stops on drawable-mdpi (which is strange... maybe a bug in Android 2.1? you could try Android 2.2 emulator)

**Why is it looking for this image? (it's not referenced in my application, I've checked). The starter activity has disabled the title bar in any case.**

This image (shadow) is not used by the title bar. It is displayed UNDER the title bar.
To make it disappear, you have to create your own theme, like this:

```
<style
  name="Theme"
  parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
  <item
    name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem making a copy of the images from drawable-ldpi/mdip/hdpi to a drawable (only drawable) folder. Put in this folder your low resolution images.

You don't need to have a title_bar_shadow.9.png file on these folders.